# How can I write a 3D list to a text file with spaces and have the commas and speech marks removed

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, text-files

This is the code I use:

```
with open('database.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in my_list:
        f.write('%s\n' % item)
    f.close()
```

It works but I want the elements within the 3D list spaced out and the commas and speech marks removed so that the text file looks more presentable.

At the moment, in the text it looks like this:

['a','b','c']

['d','e','f']

But I want it to look like this:

a b c

d e f

Answer (score 0):

Use `join` function.

```
with open('database.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in my_list:
        f.write('%s\n' % ' '.join(item))
```

Also the `f.close()` is not required here. The file gets automatically closed when you leave the `with open` block.

Comment: Thank you, I did this but then I received this error: "TypeError: sequence item 5: expected str instance, int found" What can I do from here?

Comment: If there are integers inside the list then use. `' '.join(str(i) for i in items)` .

Comment: I did this and the error went however the contents in the text file haven't ended up the way I would like them to, this is most likely since I have more internal errors within my code. Either way thanks, I'm going to try and fix my code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

you should convert the list into string :

```
with open('database.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in my_list:
        f.write('%s\n' % ' '.join(item))
    f.close()
```